# JavaScript fetch and then innerHTML problems

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var radr;
      fetch('https://example.json')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => radr = JSON.stringify(json));
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = radr;
</script>
```

Hi. I just tested this code and no matter what I do I just get undefined inserted in the element, but when I use the console it works just fine...

Comment: Your ``document.getElementById`` is NOT **_inside_** the last ``then``, move that **);** 2 lines down

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 fetch('https://example.json')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        var radr = JSON.stringify(json)
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = radr;
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since fetching of the data is async put that logic to set the html inside the last then.
It is undefined at the moment because the html is rendered before the promise is completed

```
.then(json => {
   radr = JSON.stringify(json)
   document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = radr;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var radr;
      fetch('https://example.json')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
         radr = JSON.stringify(json)
         document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = radr;
       });    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.onreadystatechange` to make sure, the DOM elements is fullyloaded.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (document.readyState === 'interactive') {
          var radr;
          fetch('https://example.json')
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(json => {
             radr = JSON.stringify(json));
            document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = radr;
           }
          }
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `querySelector("#id")` instead of `getElementById()` then you're fine. It will definitely work out.